# Must implement numberOfItemsInComboBox: and comboBox:objectValueForItemAtIndex:

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I keep getting this error in my XCode project using Swift 4.2. I am creating Mac OS Cocoa application and has a simple combobox bound to data source. Any idea?

```
 func numberOfItemsInComboBox(aComboBox: NSComboBox) -> Int {
        return weatherCitiesArray.count
    }

    func comboBox(aComboBox: NSComboBox, objectValueForItemAtIndex index: Int) -> Any? {

        if index == -1
        {
            print("recieved -1")
            return weatherCitiesArray[0]
        }

        return weatherCitiesArray[index] as AnyObject

    }
```

What is wrong with above definition of methods?

Comment: Regarding your question, I assume your class conforms to a data source protocol for combo box but you haven’t implemented the methods. Look at [this article](http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nscombobox-datasource-sample-code/)

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `NSComboBoxDataSource` to see the correct method signature for those methods?

Comment: I'd say "you should know better" is not really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your method signatures do not match those required by the `NSComboBoxDataSource` protocol which you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscomboboxdatasource). To resolve those errors, make sure that your function signatures match the protocols. Your code would end up looking something like this:

```swift
func numberOfItems(in comboBox: NSComboBox) -> Int {
    return weatherCitiesArray.count
}

func comboBox(_ comboBox: NSComboBox, objectValueForItemAt index: Int) -> Any? {
    if index == -1
    {
        print("recieved -1")
        return weatherCitiesArray[0]
    }

    return weatherCitiesArray[index] as AnyObject
}
```